# Should I save or save-dev client-side webpacked dependencies?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have dependencies that are only getting used client-side (and are getting packed into dist files on compilation through webpack). Should I save them as dev dependencies or just regular dependencies?

I'm just thinking in a server environment I'd have to recompile each time I update. Or would I? Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `--save` in your situation. `--save` is for those packages being used in production and `--save-dev` for those used when you are developing your app.

`--save` is used to save packages required for the application to run.

Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@stalonadsl948/dependencies-vs-devdependencies-926e096a3dee) for more details on what it means for a package to be a development dependency vs a dependency.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, and it is very opinion based. You don't go into detail about why `--save` is better in this situation. Especially since webpack you normally get the outputted files through some CI process, that has access to all dev packages. In production for normal use you just rely on those outputted files that were already generated as opposed to generating them on the fly, therefore not requiring webpack outside of a dev/CI environment. So WHY do you suggest using `--save`?

Comment: Yeah my thoughts exactly. But then is there some automated way (or a standard) to manage production ready files?